# Hook into ActiveRecord model RIGHT before save and after timestamps are set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am writing a computed field ActiveRecord extension (extends ActiveSupport::Concern) that needs to perform some computations on a record before it is saved. These computations may require some fields and the values of the timestamps themselves (created_at, updated_at).

However, all before_save callbacks are executed before timestamps are written to. This is because the Timestamp module overrides [create](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb#L49) and [update](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb#L63) to add the timestamps:

Does anyone know of a simple way to hook into the model right before a record is saved but after the timestamps are written? Thanks!

after_create does the job for me but it's not as clean of a solution. First, I would need to call save a second time. Second, if other gems are observing the after_create event, they may not have access to the computed fields values in time because of the way in which the callbacks are fired.

Comment: do you mean an observer?

Comment: Yes. I would like to observe a model before it gets saved but make sure the observer gets triggered AFTER the timestamps get written so that I can use their values.

Comment: have you tried rails observer? http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Observer.html You'll get much better feedback if you can illustrate why after_create didn't work for you.

Comment: I updated my question to be a bit more clear. Thanks!

Comment: You might be interested in knowing that all the callbacks, even after_save, are capable of rolling back changes made to a model. So you can use the after_save callback to access the timestamps, and then `return false` from the callback to cause a rollback.

Comment: I have this same question. What did you end up doing? Can it be posted as an answer to your own question? :)